# Heroku Django: can't find module

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am following the [Heroku instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) for Django but I'm having trouble:

```
2012-10-03T22:33:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No module named widget_tweaks
2012-10-03T22:33:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-10-03T22:33:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

For me, it seems that Heroku can't find my [django-widget-tweaks](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) app. Since I'm not using it at the moment, I tried removing it from the INSTALLED_APPS setting and also from my requirements.txt file. I then recommitted my files, pushed them back to heroku master and then tried:

```
heroku restart
```

... but the problem persists. Is there another place to remove references to this module? Any thoughts on why this module would not be found in the first place? It works fine when I deploy locally, on my django dev server on my computer.

Comment: Grep your sources for `widget_tweaks` to find out where it's coming from. You probably have a loose import somewhere.

Comment: Good idea. I have now removed all traces of widget_tweaks. When I run `grep -r -i widget_tweaks ./` I only find it in the notes in my commits. It seems gone everywhere else. But, heroku still complains that the module can't be found.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I was not pushing from my master branch. When I ran `git push heroku master` it was pushing from my master branch (where the module problems existed), even though I was checked out on another branch. I solved this by pushing from my checked out branch instead: 'git push heroku heroku_test:master'