# Successfully Deployed to Heroku however page is not showing anything

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

Hi I have successfully deployed the python django app to heroku with no errors. However when i go to the link it just does not show anything.

heroku logs show me there's some H14 error. 
Procfile.txt had been added with web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:6000

Why is the page still not showing up and it shows that no dynos are active.

URL: https://guarded-castle-63814.herokuapp.com/
[image: Error]

Comment: Make sure django-widget-tweaks is in your requirements.txt file before you push to heroku.

Comment: Yes this is also inside the requirements.txt not too sure why it’s still facing the same error

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717930/heroku-django-cant-find-module.

Comment: Hi, cant seems to be able to use git push heroku heroku_test:master

Comment: Try deleting your git repo, reinitializing it, and then push again. Basically start over.

Comment: Yup did it now it prompts me no module found for MySQLdb. Weird, i have already install pip install mysqlclient

Comment: Is that the most recent traceback?

Comment: Yes, I just tried to push it again. MySQLDB error still showing no module found. I’m using python 3.7, when I do a pip install mysqlclient it shows requirement already satisfied

Comment: I have managed to deploy to heroku successfully but i not sure why it is not displaying. it says some H14 errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `runserver` is used for develop, on production use `gunicorn`.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn config.wsgi
```

Comment: Hi, i have changed it to what you mentioned above however when i try to do a heroku ps:scale web=1 it is still showing

Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Comment: @Gerry - it should be the name of your project.wsgi. If your project name is config then the above is correct, else replace config with your project name and retry.

Comment: Yes it had been replaced by my project name. But I’m still facing the same issue. I even redeploy it but still the same